# How can I record a canvas with MediaRecorder to the exact same duration as another video?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, mediarecorder, web-mediarecorder

I have one video of duration 9200 ms, and a canvas displaying user's webcam video. I'm aiming to record the webcam video while the original video plays to create an output blob of the exact same duration with `MediaRecorder` but seem to always get a video with longer length (typically around 9400ms).

I've found that if I take the difference in durations and skip ahead in the output video by this amount it will basically sync up with the original video, but I'm hoping to not have to use this hack. Knowing this, I assumed the difference was because HTML5 video's `play()` function is asynchronous, but even calling `recorder.start()` inside a `.then()` after the `play()` promise still results in an output blob with longer duration.

I `start()` the `MediaRecorder` after `play()`ing the original video, and call `stop()` inside a `requestAnimationFrame` loop when I see that the original video has ended. Changing the `MediaRecorder.start()` to begin in the `requestAnimationFrame` loop only after checking the original video is playing also results in a longer output blob.

What might be the reason for the longer output? From the documentation it doesn't appear that `MediaRecorder`'s start or stop functions are asynchronous, so is there some way to guarantee an exact starting time with HTML5 video and `MediaRecorder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `start()` and `stop()` are async, that's why we have `onstart` and `onstop` events firing:

```js
const stream = makeEmptyStream();
const rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
rec.onstart = (evt) => { console.log( "took %sms to start", performance.now() - begin ); }; 
const begin = performance.now();
rec.start();

setTimeout( () => {
  rec.onstop = (evt) => { console.log( "took %sms to stop", performance.now() - begin ); }; 
  const begin = performance.now();
  rec.stop();
}, 1000 );

function makeEmptyStream() {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.getContext('2d').fillRect(0,0,1,1);
  return canvas.captureStream();
}
```

You can thus try to pause your video after it's been readied to play, then wait your recorder starts before starting again the playback of the video.
However, given everything in both the HTMLMediaElement and MediaRecorder is async, there is no way to get a perfect 1 to 1 relation...

```js
const vid = document.querySelector('video');
onclick = (evt) => {
onclick = null;
vid.play().then( () => {

  // pause immediately the main video
  vid.pause();
  // we may have advanced of a few µs already, so go back to beginning
  vid.currentTime = 0;
  // only when we're back to beginning
  vid.onseeked = (evt) => {

    console.log( 'recording will begin shortly, please wait until the end of the video' ); 

    console.log( 'original %ss', vid.duration );
    
    const stream = vid.captureStream ? vid.captureStream() : vid.mozCaptureStream();

    const chunks = [];
    const rec = new MediaRecorder( stream );

    rec.ondataavailable = (evt) => {
      chunks.push( evt.data );
    };
    rec.onstop = (evt) => {
      logVideoDuration( new Blob( chunks ), "recorded %ss" );
    };
    vid.onended = (evt) => {
      rec.stop();
    };
    // wait until the recorder is ready before playing the video again
    rec.onstart = (evt) => {
      vid.play();
    };

    rec.start();

  };
  
  } );

  function logVideoDuration( blob, name ) {
    const el = document.createElement('video');
    el.src = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
    el.play().then( () => {
      el.pause();
      el.onseeked = (evt) => console.log( name, el.duration );
      el.currentTime = 10e25;
    } );
  }
  
};
```

```css
video { pointer-events: none; width: 100% }
```

```html
click to start<br>
<video src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm" controls crossorigin></video>
```

Also note that there might be some discrepancy in the duration declared by your media, the calculated duration of the recorded media, and their actual duration. Indeed, these durations are often only a value hard-coded in the metadata of the files, but given how the MediaRecorder API works, it's hard to do this there, so for instance Chrome will produce files without duration, and the players will try to approximate that duration based on the last point they can seek in the media.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've tried this out in a CodePen and am empirically finding that MediaRecorder capture of a webcam stream consistently has a difference of 0.2+ seconds, whereas capture of a webm video is typically within [0, 0.2] bounds. Is this a function of media devices having some latency in capture, or is there a way to reduce this lag? CodePen here for reference https://codepen.io/joeybats/pen/eYpavKB?editors=1111

Comment: @JoeyBats ran it twice and got 34.95 and 34.977. But on a second though, I wonder if the frameRate of the stream could have any incidence on what's being recorded (technically it could, since they wouldn't have a new frame to push to the recorder, but even forcing `{ video: { frameRate: { max: 1 } } }` I still have 34.989... Still, could you check the `stream.getVideoTracks()[0].getCapabilities().frameRate` from your device?

Comment: The frameRate is an object with max value 30, which seems ok. One thing I am finding is that for videos with sound, my machine consistently has a difference of 0.2 (updated the same CodePen as above to use a source video with sound). However if I mute my tab (I am using Chrome), the recorded duration difference is very small (from 15.02 to 15.064)! Is this specific to my device, or could this actually have an effect on the MediaRecorder? I'm quite surprised to see this, since the MediaRecorder isn't of the source video but rather the webcam video.

Comment: ... I'm afraid I can't answer these questions, and that only the implementers could... You may want to open an issue on Chromium's bug tracker. On my mac OS computer, I get 15.087 with your new codepen (no significant change with or without audio track...).

Comment: Yes, I wonder if it's just a function of the device's current processes somehow -- I also find that if I scroll down to view my webcam output before clicking to start the MediaRecord, there is a similar difference of 0.1-0.2 seconds, verified on both a mac OS and windows computer.